# React event click not firing in Safari / IE

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently using React v0.14.0 and I'm not able to click on any links  generated by React on Safari v8.0.6 and IE. I've added cursor:pointer as suggested in this [link](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1169) but no luck. The same code seems to work very well on Safari (Version 9.0.1 (11601.2.7.2)) without `cursor:pointer`. Can you please help me figure out how to make it work ?
Below my code:

```
var React = require('react/addons');    
var myComponent = React.createClass({
    displayName: 'helloworld',   
    render: function () {
        var style = {cursor : 'pointer'};
        return (
            <p><a onClick={() => alert('clicked')} style={ style }>Hello World</a></p>
        );
    }
});
module.exports = myComponent;
```

Comment: Are you transpiling your code? Otherwise that `onClick={function() { alert('clicked'); }}`

Comment: Yes, but still not working.

Comment: I figured it out finally. It had to do with the Safari's unability to interpret the function syntax. Thanks @limelights

Answer (score 0):

I just changed this one : myFunction (param) {} to myFunction: function (param) {} and now all is working as it should.